# What is under my floor

Tags: flooring, asbestos, cork

[image]

I am removing vinyl flooring with cork tiles underneath and noticed some green bits under the floor. Can this be asbestos?

This flat was built in 1988 and I bought it this year

Comment: Unlikely it's asbestos but if you have any doubt, get it tested to be sure.  Is it possible that the green bits are mold or mildew forming in the organic cork due to excess moisture?  If so, you'll want to correct the problem with the moisture before re-flooring.

Comment: This is possible because when we bought the flat there was a slight damp reading in the bathroom. It's just small bits of green that I wasn't sure was glue or damp because I'm not sure how long the floor is there. The subfloor is timber also

Comment: A lot of contact cements used in flooring, especially something like cork flooring, was greenish colored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asbestos was identified in the 70’s as a health concern by the late 80’s it had strict regulations for inspecting and removal although the EPA ban in the US & many other countries also banned asbestos. Asbestos was still legal into the early 90’s in some areas if you are concerned have the material tested. Color of a material is not an indication if it has asbestos.

With all that said most contractors quit using asbestos based products prior to the mid 80’s due to lawsuits, but testing is the only way to know with certainty.